# "Error: Invalid Argument in getAmountsOut Function Call."

Tags: ethers.js, javascript, uniswapv2

```
 // Get Provider
   const providers = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider("https://");

  // Get Velodrome V1 Router
  const routerABI = [
    "function getAmountsOut(uint amountIn, route[] memory routes) public view returns (uint[] memory amounts)"
  ];
  const routerAddress = "0x9c12939390052919aF3155f41Bf4160Fd3666A6f";
  const routerContract = new ethers.Contract(routerAddress, routerABI, providers)
  let quotedAmountOut = 0; // Initialize to BigNumber 0

const routeAddresses = [inputTokenA, inputTokenB, stable=true];


console.log(routeAddresses);


try {
  quotedAmountOut = await routerContract.callStatic.getAmountsOut(amountInParsed, routeAddresses );
   console.log("quotedAmountOut:", quotedAmountOut.toString()); // Convert to string before logging
} catch (err) {
  console.error('Error occurred in getPrice:', err);
  console.error(err.stack);
  return ethers.BigNumber.from(0); // Return BigNumber 0 in case of an error
}
```

I am getting this error, i am getting
Error: invalid type,
code: 'INVALID_ARGUMENT',
argument: 'type',
value: 'route'

I have try getting getAmountsOut by passing the routesAddress,
i read the veldrome router contract where to getAmountsOut is with amountIn and routes tuple[]
please help, i will be very grateful

Comment: What is amountInParsed?

Comment: it is the variable for amountIn that i to convert to wei
let amountInParsed = ethers.utils.parseUnits(amountIn, ether);
i think the route tuple[] is the issues,  i cannot figure it out, please help me

Answer (score 1):

In your `routerABI` it seems that the type of routes is incorrect, it should be `address`.

```
const routerABI = [
  "function getAmountsOut(uint amountIn, address[] memory routes) public view returns (uint[] memory amounts)"
];
```